# Can I write "at times thick" at the end of the sentence, after a comma?

Tags: sentence-construction

From the analysis of the bonding material and (of?) the bricks, it has emerged a partial detachment of irregularly-shaped flakes, **at times thick.**

Comment: Partially detached, irregularly shaped flakes, thick at times, are seen in the analysis of blah blah blah. I don't like the verb emerge here because emerge can be literal or not.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is OK, but I would write:

> From the analysis of the bonding material and <del>of</del> the bricks, *there* has emerged a partial detachment of irregularly-shaped flakes **that are** at times thick.